# How do I make my character's arms point towards the camera or cursor in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a fps game and I want my character's arms to rotate up and down depending where the cursor/camera is pointing at. The character already rotates when I turn left or right. Hopefully someone can answer my question. I'm new to Unity and I'm still learning how to code in C#.

Answer (score 2):

For top and bottom rotation, create an animation for top aim, eye level aim and feet aim. send the value of your rotation to animator controller and animate according to it.